# How to properly serialize and deserialize paging_size in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cassandra, nosql, cql

In my `Python` application, I make the query to the `Cassandra` database. I'm trying to implement pagination through the [cassandra-driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/query_paging/#resume-paged-results) package. As you can see from the code below, `paging_state` returns the `bytes` data type. I can convert this value to the `string` data type. Then I send the value of the `str_paging_state` variable to the client. If this client sends me `str_paging_state` again I want to use it in my query.

This part of code works:

```
query = "select * from users where user_type = 'clients';"
statement = SimpleStatement(query, fetch_size=10)
results = session.execute(statement)

paging_state = results.paging_state
print(type(paging_state)) # <class 'bytes'>

str_paging_state = str(paging_state)
print(str_paging_state) # "b'\\x00C\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x02\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03_hk\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x11P]5C#\\x8bGD~\\x8b\\xc7g\\xda\\xe5rH\\xb0\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03_rk\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x18\\xee\\x14\\xf7\\x83\\x84\\x00tTmw[\\x00\\xec\\xdb\\x9b\\xa9\\xfd\\x00\\xb9\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xff\\xfe\\x01\\x00'"
```

This part of code raise error:

```
results = session.execute(
    statement,
    paging_state=bytes(str_paging_state.encode())
)
```

**Error**:

```
[ERROR] NoHostAvailable: ('Unable to complete the operation against any hosts')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 51, in lambda_handler
    results = cassandra_connection.execute(statement, paging_state=bytes(paging_state.encode()))
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2618, in execute
    return self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile, paging_state, host, execute_as).result()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 4877, in result
    raise self._final_exceptionEND RequestId: 4b7bf588-a2d2-45e5-ad7e-8611f1704313
```

In Java [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.1/com/datastax/driver/core/PagingState.html#fromString-java.lang.String-) I found the `.fromString` method which creates a `PagingState` object from a string previously generated with `toString()`. Unfortunately, I didn't find an equivalent for this method in Python.

I also tried to use [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) package to decode and encode the `paging_state`.

```
str_paging_state = codecs.decode(paging_state, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore')
# "\u0000C\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0002\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003_hk\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0011P]5C#GD~grH\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0003_rk\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0018\u0014\u0000tTmw[\u0000ۛ\u0000\u0001\u0000"

# Raise error
results = session.execute(statement, paging_state=codecs.encode(str_paging_state, encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore'))
```

In this case I see next **error**:

```
[ERROR] ProtocolException: <Error from server: code=000a [Protocol error] message="Invalid value for the paging state">
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 50, in lambda_handler
    results = cassandra_connection.execute(
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 2618, in execute
    return self.execute_async(query, parameters, trace, custom_payload, timeout, execution_profile, paging_state, host, execute_as).result()
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cassandra/cluster.py", line 4877, in result
    raise self._final_exceptionEND RequestId: 979f098a-a566-4904-821a-2ce06522d909
```

In my case, [protocol version](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/python-driver/3.24/api/cassandra/#cassandra.ProtocolVersion) is 4.

```
cluster = Cluster(..., protocol_version=4)
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the binary data into hex string or base64 - use [`binascii` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html) for that. For example, for first case functions hexlify/unhexlify (or in Python 3 use `.hex` method of binary data), and for base64 - use functions `b2a_base64`/`a2b_base64`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tested all of them. I can say that `hexlify`, `unhexlify` and `a2b_base64` functions works without any problem. But something wrong with [b2a_base64](https://docs.python.org/3/library/binascii.html#binascii.b2a_base64) function. In my case function works only without an `asterisk character` and `newline` option.

Comment: hex is most stable, base64 + HTTP may break some characters...